# Joomla: How to show menu-specific parameters for a non-MVC component

Tags: model-view-controller, parameters, menu, joomla, components

I built a Joomla 1.5 component, non-MVC, and it's working fine, so I'd rather not change it to MVC. I need to have some menu items point to my component, each menu item passing different parameters to the component. The 'Menu item specific parameters' section in http://docs.joomla.org/Component_parameters is pretty clear, except that the tutorial locates the XML file that contains the parameters assuming an MVC structure.

If my component doesn't follow MVC, where should I put that XML file, and what should be its name, so that Joomla can find it and show the parameters in the menu creation screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing to MVC. :|

Answer (score 0):

You can store those parameters in the database table. There is a parameter column where you can define any parameters you want for each menu element. This is explained in the same [joomla doc](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_parameters#Storing_the_parameters_and_their_values.) that you link to in your answer...